# on edit picklist value is changing LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightningselect

I am using a dynamic custom picklist which i am using it in lightning datatable. On load i am getting the correct values

[image]

when i click edit (custom one) the picklist value is changing the last value in picklist/

[image]

HTML -

```
<template>
    <select class="slds-select" name="optionSelect" onchange={handleChange} onselect={getselectedvalue}>
        <template for:each={pOptions} for:item="item">
            <option key={item} value={item} selected={item}>{item}</option>
        </template>
    </select>
</template>
```

JS-

```
import {api, LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    @api options;
    @api controllingfieldvalue ="A";
    @track pOptions;

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('value' + this.value);
        this.options = {"A":["1","2","3","4","5"]}
        if (this.options) {

            let opt = [];
            this.options[this.controllingfieldvalue].forEach(function (tOption) {
                opt.push(tOption);
            });
            this.pOptions = opt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if the example provided produces the issue you are encountering. When I load your exact code as a new lwc and preview locally, I get the 5 rendered on load. This is because you have the `selected={item}`. This may be the cause for your issue, but I can't be sure with the code you provided.

Comment: @hellraizer -> `when i click edit (custom one) the picklist value is changing the last value in picklist` could you further elaborate on this? i